# Vue.js watch fires despite no apparent changes in data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm running out of ideas on an issue with Vue 2 which results in a watch firing which for all I know shouldn't be firing. It happens when I am long polling an API and updating the data with the new, potentially changed, data. I want the watch to fire when data has changed, but obviously not in case no data has changed.

Let me condense it to the key parts of the code. Here's the data:

```
data() {
    return {
        ffGameState: {
            errors: {
                team1: [false, false, false]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the watch:

```
watch: {
    "ffGameState.errors.team1": {
        deep: true,
        handler: function(val, oldVal) {
            console.log("change detected")
            console.log(val)
            console.log(oldVal)
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here's the method which retrieves the data and updates the ffGameState object (it's triggered upon creation):

```
loadFfGameState() {
    var vm = this
    this.$http
    .get("/gamestates/ff")
    .then(response => {
        vm.ffGameState = response.data
    })
    .then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => this.loadFfGameState(), 100)             
    })
}
```

All of that results in the watch firing like so every single time the data is fetched (i.e. every 100 ms), see the log output from the browser:

```
change detected
AudienceScreen.vue?57f6:272 (3) [true, true, true, __ob__: Observer]
AudienceScreen.vue?57f6:273 (3) [true, true, true, __ob__: Observer]
```

The only difference I can make out at first glance is the __ob__.dep.id which changes, but I wouldn't expect this to lead to the watch firing.

Things I've tried:

- Using `this` directly instead of defining `var vm = this`
- Using `vm.$set(vm, "ffGameState", response.data)`

One more potentially useful info is that lodash's `_.isEqual(val, oldVal)` returns true.

Thanks for any help, much appreciated!

Comment: This is correct behavior. The `watch` fires whenever the watched object is *set* to a new instance. `loadFfGameState()` sets `ffGameState` to a completely new instance, which triggers the deep watcher because the subproperty array is new. If you need to prevent the action from occuring for the same value in this case, you need to manually do the comparison.

Comment: Thank you. Somehow it doesn't seem useful, though - does it mean that only simple object types can be watched? What does the ```deep: true``` option do then? Probably I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry for double post, but I think I get it. So whenever one of the fields _changes_, e.g. by assigning a new value to it by ```this.ffGameState.errors.team1 = [true, true, true]```, it will fire the watch. But not if the entire object is replaced. Is this understanding correct?


In any event, thanks a lot, I'm simply using lodash now and it works just fine. Just thought it should work with a watch in the first place.

Comment: @tony19: If you put this as a proper answer, I can accept it.
I will remove this comment after you've done so.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use a `computed` property to separate team1 like this:

```
computed: {
    team() {
        return this.ffGameState.errors.team1
    }
}
```

and then watch this computed property to handle changes only related to team1:

```
watch: {
    team: {
        deep: true,
        handler: function(val, oldVal) {
            console.log("change detected")
            console.log(val)
            console.log(oldVal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid this does not lead to the desired behavior.